# how to parse access token recived from office 365 rest api in node.js?

Tags: node.js, office365, access-token, office365api

I have to parse the access token received from office 365 rest api.
Same like this [http://jwt.calebb.net/] online tool does.
i got one peace of code in C# but i want to do it in node.js.

Comment: can u please help me :::: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813621/what-should-i-modify-in-the-https-github-com-officedev-o365-node-express-ejs-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [passport-azure-oauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-azure-oauth) module. Try this sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Node-Express-Ejs-Sample-App, it uses this module.

Even better, you should use https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs.